# Why doesn't Webpacker 4 emit CSS files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I'm wondering why, by default, webpacker 4+ doesn't create anymore CSS files?

```
# config/webpacker.yml
...
# Extract and emit a css file
extract_css: false
...
```

Is there a reason to prefer CSS files are not emited?

Comment: Not sure if this is related but webpack requires an additional plugin to extract CSS and won't do it by default, and so needs an explicit configuration to do that. This probably just mirrors that webpack decision.

Comment: I didn't have to install any additional plugin in order to create CSS files. Just change `extract_css` to `true`.

Comment: I'm talking about webpack, not webpacker. I'm assuming (not knowing how it works) that the option is used to enable the underlying webpack plugin.

Comment: I would ask this kind of question in issue in https://github.com/rails/webpacker repo

Comment: @Sig Having the same issue, but setting `extract_css` to true does not help. Do you have any loaders active in `config/webpack/development.js` or `config/webpack/environment.js`?

Comment: @Max I didn't touch any of those two files. PS - I'm on a Rails 6.0.0.rc1 app